# Initializing an array after declaration

Tags: c

gcc 4.4.3 c89

I have the following code as a sample of what I am trying to do. I don't know the actual size of the array, until I enter the function. However, I don't think I can set the array size after I have declared it. I need it global as some other functions will need to access the device names.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

```
/* global */
char *devices_names[];

void fill_devices(size_t num_devices)
{
    devices_names[num_devices];

    /* start filling */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to allocate the memory dynamically using malloc:

```
char **device_names;

void fill_devices(size_t num_devices)
{
    device_names = malloc(num_devices * sizeof(char*));
}
```

And then use `free(device_names);` to free the memory when you no longer need it.

Comment: Apologies, sepp2k. I accidentally edited your answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 3):

Make it dynamic:

```
char **g_device_names;
int g_num_devices;

void fill_devices(size_t num_devices) {
    g_device_names = malloc(sizeof(char*) * num_devices);
    g_num_devices = num_devices;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a global array then you need to know its size (or it's maximum size) at the time you declare it. E.g.

```
char *devices_names[MAX_DEVICES];
```

If you can't do this then you have no option but to use a pointer and dynamically allocated memory.

E.g.

```
char **devices_names = 0;

void fill_devices(size_t num_devices)
{
    devices_names = malloc( num_devices * sizeof *devices_names );

    /* ... */
}
```

Of course this has implications such as how do you prevent people accessing the array before it has been allocated and when do you free it?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a pointer, so when you enter the method the array is still not declared. 
You can use `malloc` to set the correct size. Look at this article: [arrays and malloc](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node11.html)