# C initializing a array or struct, CAN I do it after the declaration?

Tags: c

I know, that C allow I do it.

`char *array[] = {"String1", "String2",...};`

but I wanna do it.

`char **array or char *array[3];
array = {"String1", "String2"...};`

Because I think that using a loop to fullfill a array is very bad instead initializing like a showed.

Thanks.

Comment: `array[0] = "Foo"; array[1] = "Bar"; array[2] = "Qux";` etc? Using a loop isn't bad unless you care about microseconds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initializing an array after declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816765/initializing-an-array-after-declaration)

Comment: Of course not, it is about struct too, and this question is got a lot of interesting answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can't.

When initialising a non-static array like this, the compiler has to generate code to copy the initial state of the array out of storage and into the new array. (Because it's a *new* array every time you call the function.) It's not actually much slower to write code to do this yourself.

Long answer: if you're willing to be evil, you can sort of do it, in C99, by wrapping the array in a struct and using structure assignment...

```
struct arrayWrapper
{
  char* array[4];
};

{
  struct arrayWrapper d;
  ...
  d = (struct arrayWrapper){{1, 2, 3, 4}};
}
```

(syntax may not be quite right.)

But that's evil, and only works in C99, so don't do it, mmm'kay?

Comment: I didn't understand the cast, why it is necessary? I never saw it before.

Comment: It's not a cast, it's part of the new 'compound literal' syntax. See [this Dr.Dobbs article](http://www.drdobbs.com/184401404;jsessionid=ERHFXPB1SRPATQE1GHPSKH4ATMY32JVN). C99 is awesome, there's lots of cool stuff in it...

Comment: This answered the question, but it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: I did warn the OP it was evil!

Comment: Because this is a cunning coding trick, and cunning code tricks are usually a sign that you actually want to solve the problem in a different way. Structure initialisation like this actually compiles into a memcpy, copying the array data out of read-only storage and onto the stack. If the problem can be rephrased using pointers, you may be able to refer to the data in read-only storage directly --- which could result in faster, smaller, cleaner, more reliable and more understandable code! But, of course, it all depends what the problem actually *is*. This trick can be dead handy in its place.

Comment: This is great. I didn't even know that structure can be constructed this way.

Answer (score 3):

No -- the initialization syntax *only* works for initialization, not assignment, so it *must* be part of the array definition, not afterwards. Afterwards, what you'd have would be assigning an array instead of truly initializing it, and C does not support array assignment.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jerry says, you cannot do this for an array. Your question mentions structures, and you can do it for a structure. e.g.

```
struct mystruct {
   int a;
   int b;
};

struct mystruct mystruct;

mystruct = (struct mystruct){1, 2};
```

will assign mystruct.a to 1 and mystruct.b to 2

Comment: Okey, and if I use malloc to alloc mem for the array, can I use the same syntax? And why you made a cast to (struct mystruct)? I never saw it before.

Comment: @drigo, You can't assign an array after initialisation. The `(struct mystruct){1, 2}` is not a cast, although it looks like one. It is something called a compound literal - a way of defining a literal value for a compound type.

Answer (score 1):

Concepts at work here: **modifiable lvalue** and **compound literals vs. initializers**.

An array is not considered a **modifiable lvalue**, and so the following will never work:

```
int i[];
int j[];
i = j;
```

This includes the case where the right-hand side of the assignment is a **compound literal** like you are using.

**Compound literals** look a lot like **initializers** but they are two different concepts with similar syntax.  Initializers appear with definitions, whereas compound literals can appear in arbitrary expressions.

Since a pointer is a **modifiable lvalue**, you can assign a **compound literal** to it:

```
char** array;
array = (char* []) {"zero", "one", "two"};
```

Comment: Glad it helped. By the way, you can change the correct answer even if you've already assigned it once.

Comment: Yes, I got awesome answers, And ur one is perfect, but David given helped me a lot, cause he was the first to turn the tides to say something correct and different, he also gave me a lesson about compound literal, giving me the Dr.Dobbs article link, Sorry for can't choose two best answers, of course you made my knowledge grow a lot this day, Is hard to imagine how much amazing things I can do with it. many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for Array as Jerry has given is correct it it not for a structure.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
  int v1;
  int v2;
};


int main(void){
  struct foo v1, v2;

  v1.v1 = 1;
  v1.v2 = 2;
  v2 = v1;

  printf("v2.v1 = %d, v2.v2 = %d\n", v2.v1, v2.v1);
  return 0;
}
```